# loadVideoById() caches properties when loading same video

Tags: youtube-api

It seems like YT IFrame API will cache properties when using loadVideoById (cueVideoById too) and loading the same video in but with different properties. So if I load a video in with endSeconds at 10, and then load the same video in but with endSeconds at 25, it will still end at 10.

Here's a **plunker** to demonstrate this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/YnVmod?p=preview

Is this a known issue? Any workarounds? I am working on an app that will most likely see this kind of behavior, and so far the only solution, as far as I know, is to re-initialize the player but it's out of the question for me.

EDIT:
Looks like it's known, with a bug filed at https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5010

Comment: Your link refers to an issue with status "duplicate". It refers to an older issue: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4556

Comment: Yeah I saw that, I am not sure why those two issues were merged by their team, the behaviors and platforms it was reported on are different, not to mention this bug is still persisting. I brought it up to them so hopefully will hear something back.